# Yii2 отправка данных клиентам через WebSocket?

Tags: php, yii2, websocket

Использую библиотеку веб-сокетов [consik/yii2-websocket](https://github.com/consik/yii2-websocket).

Создал **CommandsServer** и **ServerController**

Возник вопрос, как в любом, другом контроллере отправлять сообщения клиентам?

Пробовал так:

```
    ...
    $socket = new CommandsServer();
    $socket->on(CommandsServer::EVENT_CLIENT_MESSAGE, function($e) use($socket) {
        $arr['test'] = 'test1';
        $e->client->send(json_encode($arr));
    });
    ...
```